# Not able to understand array declaration int[] it2= new int[][]{{1}}[0];

Tags: java, arrays

Please someone can help me understanding the way this array has been created.

```
int[] it2= new int[][]{{1}}[0];
```

`it2` is one dimension array and on the right hand we have weird type of initialization.
The code compiles fine, but I am able to understand how it is working.

Comment: It's usually made by programmers who don't want to make new friends.

Comment: The expression is a valid java expression. So I guess that this is about java and added the java tag. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 11):

Break the expression in parts to better understand them:

```java
int[] first = new int[]{1}; // create a new array with one element (the element is the number one)
int[][] second = new int[][]{first}; // create an array of the arrays. The only element of the outer array is the array created in the previous step.
int[] third = second[0]; // retrieve the first (and only) element of the array of array `second`. This is the same again as `first`.
```

Now we will merge those expressions again. First we merge `first` and `second`:

```
int[][] second = new int[][]{new int[]{1}};
int[] third = second[0];
```

OK, no big deal. However the expression `second` can be shortend. The following is equivalent:

```
int[][] second = new int[][]{{1}};
int[] third = second[0];
```

Now we merge second and third. We can directly write:

```
int[] third = new int[][]{{1}}[0];
```

And there we are.